# Understanding multidimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to understand the multidimensional array. I can't find a proper article to understand what the each block denotes to.

for 1D, we know that int[] = single row of elements

for 2D, int[,] = the first index denotes total rows and the second one denotes total columns

for 3D, int[,,] = I read from quora, that first index is row, second is col and the third one can be denoted to a page. So x pages with r rows and c columns. So if x is 2, r is 2 and c is 2, then there will be a total of 2 square matrices if I am correct.

for 4D, int[,,,] = He said, **a row, column and a row of page of elements (visualise it as a row of cubes)** which I cannot understand and there is no answer for 5D and beyond.

Quora answer link: https://qr.ae/pvKcLb

---

Next I found this article https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/250488-how-a-4d-and-5d-matrix-or-array-look-like-can-we-say-that-a-4d-array-is-another-for-of-3d-or-reshap#answer_197039 which says as below

1. A vector is an array of scalars.
2. A 2D matrix is an array of vectors.
3. A 3D array is an array of 2D matrices.
4. A 4D array is an array of 3D arrays.
5. A 5D array is an array of 4D arrays.
6. Etc.

So, since his answer looked quiet understandable, I tried coding instead of visualizing and I ended up with the below snippet!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PracticeCSharp.CSharp
{
    class CSL10
    {
        public void MultiDArrExample()
        {
            int[] _1D = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };


            int[,] _2D = new int[,]
            {
                { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
                { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
            };

            int[,,] _3D = new int[,,]
            {
                {
                    { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
                    { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
                },
                {
                    { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
                    { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
                }
            };

            int[,,,] _4D = new int[,,,]
            {
                {
                    {
                        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
                        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
                    },
                    {
                        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
                        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
                    }
                },
                {
                    {
                        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
                        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
                    },
                    {
                        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
                        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
                    }
                }
            };

            //My head started spinning.. and cant go further.. 
        }
    }
}
```

Can you help to understand this multidimensional array? and what are some real world use cases and what are the alternatives for this multi-D-arrays?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1D- a sentence. 2D- a page. 3D- a book. 4D- a library. 5D- libraries in your town. 6D- towns in your state. 7D- states in your country. 8D- countries on your planet. 9D- planets in your ever so literary solar system..

Comment: @CaiusJard  So, it must be something like 
int[row,col,page_with_row_cols,book_with_pages,library_with_books,town_with_libraries,state_with_towns,country_with_states,Continent_with_countries,earth_with_continents] and so on... right?

Comment: It's hard to help you understand without knowing what it is you're _not_ understanding.  You initialize various arrays but don't actually use them, so perhaps writing code to do so would be beneficial. Try this: write some code to store the state of an 8 × 8 chess board using `int[,] board = new int[8, 8];` where `0` means empty, `1` is a pawn, `2` is a bishop, etc. (the values don't really matter) and print it out row by row. Then, try to do the same thing using `int[] board = new int[64];` and see how the two representations are related.  _Then_, repeat the above but for **10** chess boards.

Comment: @Thameem it's any hierarchy you want. Put 10 files in a folder on your hard disk, duplicate that folder 10 times, now put the 10 folders in another folder and duplicate *that* folder 10 times. Now do it again. And again. Eventually you might have a path c:\folders\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder6\folder5\folder4\file.txt - it's conceptually a 6 or 7 dimension thing. In an array it might be folders[1,2,3,6,5,4]. It's just a path through a hierarchy, to a value

Comment: @CaiusJard -> yeah I get that, i just used that book to earth flow as an example. thanks

Comment: It's probably worth noting that this is one of the reasons why we do object oriented programming; it makes these hierarchies easier to reason about. Instead of having an array that is [planet,country,state,town,linrary,book,page,sentence] we have a class Planet that has a List<Country>, and Coubtry has a List<State>, and State has a... they're the same thing, representing hierarchy of data but the class form is much easier to reason about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I was trying to understand what each part of an array indicates in order to understand the multi-dimensional array. I understood it then

I just wanted to understand the way of denoting the different portions of an array. And thanks to **Caius Jard** I understood how it works and I am able to successfully do an object initialization on the multi-dimensional array. I've done upto 6D and it goes on. I am adding the code to the answer, for any one who might need that to understand how the MultiD-Array works

Here is the object initialization code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PracticeCSharp.CSharp
{
    class CSL10
    {
        public void MultiDArrExample()
        {
            //1 dimensional
            //Line
            int[] _1D = new int[] { 5, 5 };

            //2 dimensional
            //Paragraph
            int[,] _2D = new int[,]
            {
                {5, 5 },
                {5, 5 }
            };

            //3 dimensional
            //A page with paragraphs
            int[,,] _3D = new int[1, 2, 2]
            {
                {
                    {5, 5 },
                    {5, 5 }
                }
            };

            //3 dimensional
            //A book with 2 pages and 2,2 paragraphs in each page
            int[,,,] _4D = new int[1, 2, 2, 2]
            {
                //Book 1
                {
                    //Page 1
                    {
                        //Para
                        {5, 5 },
                        {5, 5 }
                    },

                    //Page 2
                    {
                        //Para
                        {5, 5 },
                        {5, 5 }
                    }
                }
            };

            //5 dimensional
            //A library with 2 books with 2 pages and 2,2 paragraphs in each page
            int[,,,,] _5D = new int[1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
            {
                //Library
                {
                    //Book 1
                    {
                        //Page 1
                        {
                            //Para
                            {5, 5 },
                            {5, 5 }
                        },

                        //Page 2
                        {
                            //Para
                            {5, 5 },
                            {5, 5 }
                        }
                    },
                    //Book 2
                    {
                        //Page 1
                        {
                            //Para
                            {5, 5 },
                            {5, 5 }
                        },

                        //Page 2
                        {
                            //Para
                            {5, 5 },
                            {5, 5 }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            //6 dimensional
            //A town with 2 libraries with 2 books each with 2 pages in each book and 2,2 paragraphs in each page
            int[,,,,,] _6D = new int[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
            {
                //town
                {
                    //Library 1
                    {
                        //Book 1
                        {
                            //Page 1
                            {
                                //Para
                                {5, 5 },
                                {5, 5 }
                            },

                            //Page 2
                            {
                                //Para
                                {5, 5 },
                                {5, 5 }
                            }
                        },
                        //Book 2
                        {
                            //Page 1
                            {
                                //Para
                                {5, 5 },
                                {5, 5 }
                            },

                            //Page 2
                            {
                                //Para
                                {5, 5 },
                                {5, 5 }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    //Library 2
                    {
                        //Book 1
                        {
                            //Page 1
                            {
                                //Para
                                {5, 5 },
                                {5, 5 }
                            },

                            //Page 2
                            {
                                //Para
                                {5, 5 },
                                {5, 5 }
                            }
                        },
                        //Book 2
                        {
                            //Page 1
                            {
                                //Para
                                {5, 5 },
                                {5, 5 }
                            },

                            //Page 2
                            {
                                //Para
                                {5, 5 },
                                {5, 5 }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Then Iterating a 6D array

```
//Iterating a 6D array
int totalTowns = 1;
int totalLibrariesInEachTown = 2;
int totalBooksInEachLibrary = 2;
int totalPagesInEachBook = 2;
int totalRowsInEachPage = 2;
int totalColsInEachPage = 2;

int count = 1;
for (int town = 0; town < totalTowns; town++)
{
    for (int library = 0; library < totalLibrariesInEachTown; library++)
    {
        for (int book = 0; book < totalBooksInEachLibrary; book++)
        {
            for (int page = 0; page < totalPagesInEachBook; page++)
            {
                for (int row = 0; row < totalRowsInEachPage; row++)
                {
                    for (int col = 0; col < totalColsInEachPage; col++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Count: {count++} Reading array location " +
                            $"[{town},{library},{book},{page},{row},{col}] = " +
                            _6D[town, library, book, page, row, col]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We live in a 3D world, so anything beyond these 3 dimensions becomes difficult for us humans to visualise and imagine.

But this is no problem for a computer.  Which can support an almost endless number of dimensions (depending on memory, processing power, etc.)

However, it does mean that it is impossible to find a "real world" example of a 4/5/21 dimensional array.  Because there simply aren't any in our world!

See also this article, which explains a bit more and has some more links:

https://www.preposterousuniverse.com/blog/2009/03/30/why-cant-we-visualize-more-than-three-dimensions/

Comment: I suppose we do have time as an aid to visualizing the fourth dimension..